# AJAX not working when more than one line is in the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Rendering a partial using AJAX

```
$('#next_videos').replaceWith('<%= render(:partial => 'videos')%>');
```

is my js

the partial im rendering i dumbed down to isolate the problem

```
<p> Testing </p>
```

so this works fine but when you add any ruby comments e.g.

```
<p> Testing </p>
<%# holder = videos_counter %>
```

nothing happens. The server shows that it processes it fine but no changes occur on the web page.  Any clue as to what's going on here?  Thanks.

Using rails 3.1.1, sqlite3, formtastic 2.0.2, devise 1.5.1, and whenever

Edit:

The AJAX update isn't working when there is more than one line in my partial.  For example,

```
<p> Testing </p> <p> Testing </p>
```

will work but

```
<p> Testing </p>
<p> Testing </p>
```

will not.

Comment: Do you see errors in your FireBug console?

Comment: @Darin All Firebug shows is a 304 not modified but that comes up both when the AJAX works and when it doesn't

Comment: Steve, and when you look at the Response tab do you see the HTML sent by the server?

Comment: @Darin yes, it's the same when it works and when it doesn't. This is what i get:

$('#next_videos').replaceWith('<p> Testing </p> <p> Testing </p>');

Comment: @Darin Also the 304 not modified happens only when I try using the remote link more than once.  I get a 200 OK the first time its used regardless of whether I can see the change on the web page or not.

Comment: @Darin I just noticed this error:
Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try escaping the markup using the [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper or its `j` alias:

```
$('#next_videos').replaceWith('<%=j render(:partial => 'videos') %>');
```

Comment: You're a boss, it worked!  I read about the issue with escaping the javascript but in the example I used they weren't using it.  Why does it work (without escaping_javascript) for the first line of markup but not any subsequent ones?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Steve, it doesn't work with the second line because there's a new line in the script which breaks your javascript. It would also have broken it if your markup contained for example a single quote. That's the reason why you should always escape it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov for me it doesn't work even after escaping js, any idea what else could be wrong? (i'm trying to load 3 partials via ajax)